# Two instances of plugin on one event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a plugin that reacts on mousemove, and if i call second instance of same plugin, it ovewrites bindings of first call.
How do i create plugin that can use same event with different settings?

```
(function($, document){
  $.fn.parallax = function(options){    
    options = $.extend({
        speed: .4,
        speedY: .2,
        random: false
    }, options);
    $this = this;
    var cursor = {};
    cursor.delta = {};
    cursor.X = 0;
    cursor.Y = 0;

    $this.children().each(function(ind, layer) {                
        if (options.random) {
            $(layer).data("speedX",Math.random()*options.speed);
            $(layer).data("speedY",Math.random()*options.speedY);
        };
    }) 

    $(document).mousemove(function(event) { 
        cursor.delta.X =  $this.offset().left - cursor.X;
        cursor.delta.Y =  $this.offset().top - cursor.Y;
        cursor.X = +event.pageX;
        cursor.Y = +event.pageY;      
        $this.children().each(function(ind, layer) {                
            startX = +$(layer).css("left");
            startY = +$(layer).css("top");
            speedX = $(layer).data("speedX")?$(layer).data("speedX"):options.speed;
            speedY = $(layer).data("speedY")?$(layer).data("speedY"):options.speedY;               

            $(layer).css({
                transform : "translate("+ (cursor.delta.X*speedX) +"px, "+ (cursor.delta.Y*speedY) +"px)"
            },100);
        }) 
        console.log($this);      

    }); 
    return this;

  };
})(jQuery, document);
```

Comment: Can you make an online demo for it?

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/s80b906h/
Logos moving, but i have called plugin on logos and rocks, and want both of them move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was here:

```
$this = this;
```

js created global $this, and overwrote it on second call.
Solution is var, it will create local $this, and will change them accordingly

```
var $this = this;
```

More over you can avoid this kind of problem by introduce [`'use strict'` mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1335875/3186681) which will throw error when unsafe actions are taken such as gaining access to the global object.